# How do I pass an unflattened array repetition to a reduce in Perl 6?

Tags: arrays, perl, raku

I'm trying to pass an xx repeated array to an [X~] reduce function but finding that the array gets flattened. I've searched the online docs and stack overflow, but couldn't find anything. Unfortunately, my Perl 6 knowledge is quite rudimentary (though I do know Perl 5 quite well).

```
[X~](<1 2>, <1 2>)    # 11 12 21 22 (WHAT I WANT)
[X~](<1 2> xx 2)      # 1 2 1 2 (NOT WHAT I WANT)
[X~](<1 2> xx 2).tree # 1 2 1 2
[X~](<1 2>.tree xx 2) # 1 2 1 2
```

Looking at the .perl dumps doesn't enlighten me much:

```
(<1 2>, <1 2>).perl    # (("1", "2"), ("1", "2"))
(<1 2> xx 2).perl      # (("1", "2"), ("1", "2")).list
(<1 2> xx 2).tree.perl # ("1", "2"; "1", "2").item
```

I'm using rakudo-star-2014.12.1-parrot.msi.

Comment: Any particular reason why you went with Parrot instead of MoarVM?

Comment: Not really. This was my first install, just to get a flavor of the language. Reading more on http://rakudo.org/ I understand that the MoarVM backend is the one to use.

Comment: `<1 2>` is not an array.

Comment: @райтфолд: you're right, it's a word list (though http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/perl6/ actually calls it an array; e.g. search for <key1 value1 key2 value2>). I forget that Perl doesn't have a word for an arbitrary thing in list context.

Comment: @UriZarfaty Whooops, I'll fix it :-). nice cath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you also want your code to work with arrays repeated more than twice, the workaround I came up with reads

```
(<1 2> xx 2).tree.reduce({ @^a X~ @^b })
```

Note that flattening behaviour and the List/Parcel distinction<sup>1</sup> are known pain points.

A plan to improve the situation has been around for a while (cf [Great List Refactor](http://pmthium.com/2014/10/apw2014/)) and is supposed to land before the 6.0 release at the end of the year.

<sup>1</sup> All three expressions you looked at have different types:

```
(<1 2>, <1 2>).WHAT    # (Parcel)
(<1 2> xx 2).WHAT      # (List)
(<1 2> xx 2).tree.WHAT # (LoL)
```

The last one is a List-of-Lists.

Comment: Along the same lines: `([1,2] xx 2).map: { @^a X~ @^b }`

Comment: @raiph: `.map` will fails once you generalize from the `xx 2` example to `xx 3` or higher

Comment: D'oh. Should be `say ([1,2] xx 3).reduce: { @^a X~ @^b}`